# Getting control's position placed in scroll-able container

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollable

I have control/user controls placed in a scroll able container. 
Now if a user has scrolled, then the control's position changes. 
I want to save the position of a few user controls (which are movable),
 so that I can load it on a specified position on the next load. 
The issue is, if a user has scrolled in the container then the positions are 
not the exact location in the container. How can I get the exact position in the container?

I tried to add scroll position which will fix the issue,
but my user control may be used in nested scrollable 
controls in the future so it will create issues. 
The save position code is at user control.

Comment: _Now if a user has scrolled, then the control's position changes_.The position of the control doesn't change after scrolling. Only after moving.

Comment: Offset it by the container's AutoScrollPosition.